# RMarkdown: Statamarkdown produces undesired output when collectcode=TRUE

Tags: r, markdown, stata

I'm using [`Statamarkdown`](https://www.ssc.wisc.edu/%7Ehemken/Stataworkshops/Stata%20and%20R%20Markdown/StataMarkdown.html) to produce HTML documents using `RMarkdown` and Stata.

As documented [here](https://www.ssc.wisc.edu/%7Ehemken/Stataworkshops/Stata%20and%20R%20Markdown/StataProfile.html), each code chunk is executed as a separate Stata session. `collectcode=TRUE` is a chunk option to collect Stata code across chunks.

While this works neatly, the outputs of the second (and any further) chunks follwing the first with `collectcode=TRUE` contain an undesired echo at the top:

> Running .......\profile.do

For instance, when running a second chunk with `{stata stata2, echo = T,collectcode=TRUE}`

```
   reg mpg price i.foreign ,  noheader
```

yields this output:

```
reg mpg price i.foreign ,  noheader  
Running C:\Cloud\Methods\prog\profile.do . reg mpg price i.foreign ,  noheader  
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
         mpg |      Coef.   Std. Err.      t    P>|t|     [95% Conf. Interval]
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
       price |   -.000959   .0001815    -5.28   0.000     -.001321    -.000597
             |
     foreign |
    Foreign  |   5.245271   1.163592     4.51   0.000     2.925135    7.565407
       _cons |   25.65058   1.271581    20.17   0.000     23.11512    28.18605
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Here's my RMarkdown repex:

````
---
title: "Statamarkdown output problem"
output: html_document
---

```{r setup, include = F}
library(Statamarkdown)
```


First chunk is clean:

```{stata stata1,collectcode=TRUE}
sysuse auto
su mpg price
```

Second Stata Output contains undesired `Running .......\profile.do` output:

```{stata stata2, echo = T,collectcode=TRUE}
reg mpg price i.foreign ,  noheader  
```

Problem persists even in chunks with `collectcode=FALSE`:

```{stata new_data, echo = T,collectcode=F}
webuse bpwide, clear
su sex agegrp
```

`cleanlog = F` does not do the trick:
```{stata new_data2, echo = T,collectcode=F, cleanlog = FALSE}
webuse bpwide, clear
su sex agegrp
```
````

Avoiding `collectcode=T` alltogether, i.e. load and preparing the data for each chunks would of course be a workaround, but extremely tedious.

I'm using R 3.6.3 and Stata 16.1 on a Windows machine.

Any ideas are very much appreciated!

Comment: Thank you! Unfortunately, removing `echo` does not change the problematic output

Avoiding `collectcode` breaks the code as is. I would have to do 
`sysuse auto` and `reg mpg price i.foreign ,  noheader` within the same chunk.
Which is not a problem is this example. However, usually some preparation is necessary before running the model etc. That is why dropping `collectcode=T` is not an option here

Comment: I included both `echo` and `collectcode` in all chunks. Your code has no problem on my machine.

Comment: Thank you very much! I should've added more info to my question: I'm using Windows10, R 3.6.3 and Stata16.1 - Does your setup differ in any regard?

Comment: I use Windows 10, R 4.02, Stata 14. Statamarkdown 0.4.5. I have tried various combinations but could not reproduce your problem. I might have missed something though. I will have a look tomorrow if you still have problem

Comment: Thank you very much! It seems to be a problem with Stata16 - switching to Stata13 solved the problematic output, but creates line breaks in the output tables. For now I could solve that using `set linesize 200`. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out Stata changed from

```
running .......\profile.do
```

to

```
Running .......\profile.do
```

A new version of the Statamarkdown package (0.5.0) accomodates this, now.